# Send lon/lat & description from html table cell to google earth

Tags: google-earth, kmz

I have a table in an html page where each cell contains one line whose elements are separated by spaces:

09/04/2011 16:06:23 Suspect Vessel, INDIAN OCEAN 14 16 N 056 32 E

Each row cell contains similar entries. What would be the best way to extract these elements and send them as a label to GoogleEarth (KMZ?) and have it run automatically every day so any new entries are added to the map?

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the entries and put them into KML as placemarks

Here's the sample KML from Google:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Google Earth - New Placemark</name>
  <description>Some Descriptive text.</description>
  <LookAt>
    <longitude>-90.86879847669974</longitude>
    <latitude>48.25330383601299</latitude>
    <range>440.8</range>
    <tilt>8.3</tilt>
    <heading>2.7</heading>
  </LookAt>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-90.86948943473118,48.25450093195546,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#placemark

You can add an icon to the placemark to make it look a little nicer:

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#icon

You really only need to use a KMZ if you want to include custom images/icons for the placemark.